# Shallow router push in Next.js 13 with appDir enabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, next.js13

In < Next 13 (or with appDir disabled), you could do:

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  const router = useRouter();

  const toggleStatic = () => {  
    if (router.query.static) {
      router.push(router.pathname, router.pathname, { shallow: true });
    } else {
      router.push(router.pathname, router.pathname + "?static", { shallow: true });
    }
  }

  return <>
    // ...
  </>

});
```

This would perform a shallow router update that would change the location, but not push it to history or trigger a page load.

Now, with appDir enabled, you need to import functions from `next/navigation` instead. But the [docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/linking-and-navigating#userouter-hook) don't say anything about shallow router pushing using the new router?

All I can do is this:

```
const router = useRouter();
const pathname = usePathname();
const searchParams = useSearchParams();

const toggleStatic = () => {
  if (searchParams.get("static")) {
    router.push(pathname);
  } else {
    router.push(pathname + "?static");
  }
};
```

But that does a full page reload. Is there a way to replicate the shallow router functionality using Next 13's appDir?

Comment: see https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/48110

Answer (score 1):

Try the `replace` method instead of `push`:

```
const router = useRouter();
const pathname = usePathname();
const searchParams = useSearchParams();

const toggleStatic = () => {
  if (searchParams.get("static")) {
    router.replace(pathname);
  } else {
    router.replace(pathname + "?static");
  }
};
```

[useRouter in nextjs docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#userouter).

Comment: Downside to this is it then doesn't update the history. Shallow routing updated history alongside the page draw.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a custom hooks that solves it in my case:

```
export function useShallowNavigation(defaultValues: Record<string, unknown> = {}) {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const [params, setParams] = useState(
    Object.entries(defaultValues).reduce((agg, [key, value]) => {
      if (!agg[key]) agg[key] = String(value);
      return agg;
    }, Object.fromEntries(searchParams.entries()))
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const newUrl = Object.keys(params).length
      ? `${pathname}?${new URLSearchParams(params).toString()}`
      : pathname;

    if (newUrl !== window.location.pathname + window.location.search) {
      window.history.pushState(
        { ...window.history.state, as: newUrl, url: newUrl },
        '',
        newUrl
      );
    }
  }, [pathname, params]);

  return [params, setParams] as const;
}
```

The key is to handle the query parameters in an object state, and then sync the url from that state.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add scroll option to router.push { scroll: false }.

```js
router.push('/updated-route', { scroll: false });
```

Documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating#disabling-scroll-restoration

Also you can check this thread: [Next.js - router.push without scrolling to the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65902664/next-js-router-push-without-scrolling-to-the-top)